# Having issues on if-else statement on the text changed event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have a little bit issue here on my html text changed event in regards with my if-else statement. Here's the scenario, I have the html layout below which has a dropdown list of all locations. Now, if type in your location on the input text box which has id of **"#searchloc"** it will query as you typed in and rebind the record list on the **"#dropdownlist"** div element. So my problem is, I want to rebind the **"#dropdownlist"** div element back to its default which shows all locations once I clear back or empty the **"#searchloc"** input textbox but the **"#dropdownlist"** div element remained clear or empty. Below I tried to use if-else statement to do this but I notice that under the **else{...}** statement it won't fire the function or even the alert method. How do I handle this type of issue in jquery?

**HTML Layout:**

```
<input type="text" id="searchloc" class="searchloc" onchange = "QueryLocation();" onkeydown="this.onchange();" onkeyup="this.onchange();" onkeypress = "this.onchange();" oninput = "this.onchange();" placeholder="Search Location"  />

   <div id="dropdownlist" data-bind="foreach: PopulateAllLocation" >

    <div id="alllocationdiv" > <label id="listlocation" class="listlocation" data-bind="text: CityTown"></label></div>   

 </div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
// Change the dropdownlist result as text input change
    function QueryLocation() {
        if ($("#searchloc").val() != null) {
            var dataObject = {
                CityTown: $("#searchloc").val()
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: '/OnlineStore/SearchLocation',
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: dataObject,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    self.PopulateAllLocation(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log('err')
                }
            });
        }
        else {
// Under this else statement won't fire any of this function...???
             DisplayLocations();
            alert("Textbox is empty...");

        }

    }
```

Comment: use keyup() instead of change :)

Comment: @Amit I used keyup() also checkout my html layout

Comment: try changing this if ($("#searchloc").val() != null) to if ($("#searchloc").val().length > 0).

Comment: @Amit Nope it's still working the same thing.

Comment: remove all events and just try for onkeyup = "QueryLocation();".

Comment: else check your debugger whether it is showing any error.

Comment: @Amit using the keyup only will give me the previous result which it will perform the if{..} statement but won't perform the else statement once you clear the textbox. I check the debugger and I don't see any error however in the console I see something like this Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. What does it means?

Comment: @Amit I got now thanks. It should be keyup() but under the else {...} I need to create another ajax call to rebind the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you check for a value of an empty `textbox` in Javascript its not `null` its `""` **i.e empty string** instead. So in your `if` condition the value is never equal to null, that is the reason the `else` part is never executed.

```
 function QueryLocation() {
        if ($("#searchloc").val() != "") {
            var dataObject = {
                CityTown: $("#searchloc").val()
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: '/OnlineStore/SearchLocation',
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: dataObject,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    self.PopulateAllLocation(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log('err')
                }
            });
        }
        else {

             DisplayLocations();
            alert("Textbox is empty...");

        }

    }
```

Comment: I have tried this also. Problem is it will not perform the if{...} statement anymore as I type in the search term

Comment: are you sure?? because this is the right way of doing it.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure It won't do anything once started typing in unlike before

Comment: then the problem is something else

Comment: Yes, Thanks I figure it out now. Your answer is correct. My fault is I need to call another ajax call rather than using the previous DisplayLocations(); function to rebind the data using knockout. Thanks for your help. Cheers